# Fourier series using mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, series-expansion, fourier-analysis

I want to check my homework answers. So I am wondering if there is a way you can find Fourier series using mathematica of this function g(x)=x(1-x) on interval [0,1)? If so, can someone please show me how you can using *Mathematica*?

Comment: A first step might be to enter "fourier series" into the search bar of the documentation center.

Comment: To be more specific, just try e.g. `rst=easyFourierSinSeries[x(1-x),{x,0,1}]; Plot[{x(1-x),rst/.C->2//ReleaseHold}//Evaluate,{x,0,1}]`.

Answer (score 3):

It is important to say what the period is. Taking the period as 1 in your case, then your function looks like

```
g[x_] := Piecewise[{{x (1 - x), 
     0 <=  x < 1}, {-x (1 + x), -1 <=  x < 0}, {0, True}}];
Plot[g[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above assumes even periodic extension. To find the Fourier series now use

```
fs = FourierSeries[g[x], x, 3, FourierParameters -> {1, -2 Pi}];
fs // ExpToTrig
Plot[{g[x], fs}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

$$
-\frac{\cos (2 \pi  x)}{\pi ^2}-\frac{\cos (4 \pi  x)}{4 \pi ^2}-\frac{\cos (6 \pi  x)}{9 \pi ^2}+\frac{1}{6}
$$

[image: Mathematica graphics]

More terms produces better approximation

```
fs = FourierSeries[g[x], x, 7, FourierParameters -> {1, -2 Pi}];
fs // ExpToTrig
Plot[{g[x], fs}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

$$
-\frac{\cos (2 \pi  x)}{\pi ^2}-\frac{\cos (4 \pi  x)}{4 \pi ^2}-\frac{\cos (6 \pi  x)}{9 \pi ^2}-\frac{\cos (8 \pi  x)}{16 \pi ^2}-\frac{\cos (10 \pi  x)}{25 \pi
   ^2}-\frac{\cos (12 \pi  x)}{36 \pi ^2}-\frac{\cos (14 \pi  x)}{49 \pi ^2}+\frac{1}{6}
$$

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you!! I appreciate it!